# How to check number of shards there in Redis ? I did check cli but there isn't one to show it

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

How to check number of shards there in Redis?

I have searched net and redis documentation there isn't simple way to get current shards count in my redis cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Redis uses the term *SLOT* instead of *SHARDS*. The slot number is fixed, and there are `16384` slots.

Also you can use `CLUSTER SLOTS` command to get the slot-node mapping, i.e. which node serves a given slot or slot range.

Answer (score 1):

The cluster_size and cluster_known_nodes fields within the output of the cluster info (https://redis.io/commands/cluster-info) command should give you what you are looking for.